# Assemble, Handlebars partial, YAML Front matter

Tags: html, yaml, handlebars.js, assemble

I have a partial... e.g: **partial.hbs**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

I want to use this partial but pass the YAML "title" in another partial e.g: **page.hbs**

```
---
 title: hello
---
{{> partial}}
```

is this possible without writing a custom helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Assemble 0.4.x with Handlebars 2.x you should be able to [pass arguments to partials](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/182), so your use of the **partial.hbs** would be something like:

**page.hbs**

```
---
 title: hello
---
{{> partial title=title}}
```

just be sure you are using Handlebars <=2.0 which supports partial parameters/arguments.

otherwise you could take a look at the [handlebars-helper-partial](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-partial) which can do this with <2.0 Handlebars.

hope this helps.